# Facebook API Session contents randomly changing

Tags: php, facebook, session

So I posted a previous question before about this, but deleted it because I've discovered my problem.

Basically, I was getting this error:

> Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.

I was able to pinpoint that for some bizarre reason, my `$_SESSION['FBRLH_state']` as changing. Here is the `login.php` that generates the login url for the user:

```
session_start();
}
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook ([
    'app_id' => '??????',
    'app_secret' => '????',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
    ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://example.ca/login-callback.php');
echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Login</a>';
print_r($_SESSION);
```

When I do a `print_r($_SESSION);`, I get this:

```
Array ( [FBRLH_state] => d116b427b433a0b3dc41a858782cd690 )
```

**However** (get ready for the magic), upon redirection to the `login-callback.php` file, the array of `$_SESSION` mysteriously changes to this:

```
Array ( [FBRLH_state] => e99c4ece0f8e48ab53dea6a4826c5593 )
```

Here is the code for `login-callback.php`

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8");
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/Database.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/User.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vars/constants.php';

//Create the Facebook service
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook ([
    'app_id' => '????',
    'app_secret' => '????',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
    ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
    $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
    // When Graph returns an error
    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
    $mysqli = Database::connection();

    // Logged in!
    $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
```

When I print `$_SESSION` (the first thing I do right after the `headers`), I get a completely different value from the `login.php` one. It makes no sense because they're both on the same domain (non-www) and they have the same `document.cookie` `PHPSESSID`

**But**, there's a catch. If I press back on `login-callback.php` (since `login.php` redirects to it, and then the login fails due to this weird session magic), the `$_SESSION` values mysteriously match. This **doesn't** work if I refresh, ONLY when I press back. I think this is some important clue as to what's going on but I have no idea.

Can someone please help me on this extremely frustrating issue? Anyone with any idea of what might be going on?

Edit: Also, I created a blank file with just

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
```

And the values I get **always** match `login-callback.php` which means that `login.php` must be changing some session values (but.... I can't figure out how since when I `print_r($_SESSION);` at the bottom of the file I still get the same weird values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weirdest solution, the problem was solved when I removed the `</head>` (basically I let `<head>` be unclosed)

Comment: That’s doesn’t sound like a real “solution”, but rather an implicit fix to a different problem with your code …